# How to avoid typeid with better abstraction?

Tags: c++

I am using typeid in my code, but it seems to me that the code can be cleaner if I avoid typeid.

If we want to store the type of the class, why would we choose an object-oriented language in the first place?

But I see this pattern over and over again and I do not know how to avoid it.

So I am thinking if this code can be written cleaner with a better abstraction?

Here is the code:

```
class A {
public:
    string type;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A {
public:
    B() {
        type = typeid(T).name();
    }
};

class Registry {
private:
    std::vector<A *> list;
public:
    void append(A * a) {
        int found = 0;
        for (A * el : list) {
            if (a->type == el->type) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        list.push_back(a);
    }

    int size() {
        return list.size();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Registry reg;

    A * b_int1 = new B<int>();
    A * b_int2 = new B<int>();
    A * b_float = new B<float>();

    reg.append(b_int1);
    reg.append(b_int2);
    reg.append(b_float);

    cout << reg.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 2. (which is the expected result)

Basically we do not want to store two object of the same type in a list.

Comment: `typeid(T).name();` this is not guaranteed to be meaningful... So better just store the `type_info` returned.

Comment: Quickly: Why do you store the name of the type instead of the `type_info` itself? `type_info` has an overloaded `operator==`.

Comment: Visitor pattern is your friend.

Comment: @lorro, more like an anti-pattern for unstable class hierarchies. Unless you implement the a-cyclic visitor pattern, but that just goes back to using RTTI.

Comment: @arash what should happen if you would add an object of `class C : public B<int> { ...};` ?  (currently the result would still be 2, but is it the expected behavior ?)

Comment: Why is A not polymorphic?

Comment: @Christophe: if there is class C : public B<int> { public: C():B< int >() {} }; the result must be still 2 because we have one int in the list already. Yes, the expected result is 2.

Comment: Is it really the type of the template parameter you're interested in and not the type of the object itself?

Comment: @molbdnilo: Yes, I am interested in the type of object. But how can you distinguish between B<int> and B<float> without considering the type of template parameter?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Could you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: @arash Compare `typeid(*a)` and `typeid(*el)` in `append`. You'll need at least one virtual function in the base class. The destructor is a popular choice.

Comment: @arash: "*Basically we do not want to store two object of the same type in a list.*" ... why? What is it that you're doing where you need a list of (polymorphic) values, but each value *must be* of a different type? It seems to me that you're doing something wrong with types if you need to do that "over and over again".

Comment: @NicolBolas: This is the requirement of the application. The registry keeps some "objects" and these objects are running on different machines. The registry wants to avoid creating objects of the same type. If someone asks to add a new object of the same type, the registry first searches to see if the object already exists. If so, it returns the object for reuse. If not, it creates a new one.

Comment: **−1** You can always just use a `std::set<std::type_index>`. But I don't see any point here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question appears to be meaningless. Noting that for the literal question a `std::set` or a `std::map` does the job, depending on exactly what the job is.

Comment: Sounds like the use case for the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

Comment: @arash: Then you're using the type system wrong. You're trying to use types as a unique identifier. You should use types as *types*, not identifiers for objects. If each "object" is running on a different machine, then those machines should have/be assigned unique IDs. And if the user wants to create/access one, they do so by ID, not by C++ type.

Comment: Are the registered types known at compile time ?

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, they are known.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I realized that I try to over-simplify things and that causes problem. I got many great responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want visitors, but you'd like a quick RTTI, I'd suggest looking into this paper: http://www.stroustrup.com/fast_dynamic_casting.pdf

The idea is:

- Each class is assigned a distinct prime number for it's own type (e.g., `A::my_type = 2`; `B::my_type = 3`)
- Then each class is additionally assigned the product of its type and base class values if any (e.g., `A::can_cast = A::my_type`; `B::can_cast = B::my_type * A::can_cast;` )

This solves the `is_same_dynamic()`, `is_base_dynamic()` problems elegantly: former becomes `==`, latter becomes `%`.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether or not an object belongs to a class derived from a given class, one might use the `dynamic_cast<T*>` and compare the result with `nullptr`. Unfortunately, given that we need to check this fact to the unknown type, we are forced to implement such comparison method once per each descendant of class `A`, but this may be simplified using `#define`.

Summing up, I would probably write it like this:

```
#define TYPE_COMPARISON \
virtual bool compare(A* rhs) \
{ \
  return dynamic_cast<decltype(this)>(rhs) != nullptr; \
}

class A {
public:
  TYPE_COMPARISON
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A {
public:
  TYPE_COMPARISON
};

class Registry {
private:
  std::vector<A *> list;
public:
  void append(A * a) {
    int found = 0;
    for (A * el : list) {
      if (a->compare(el) && el->compare(a)) {
        found = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found)
      list.push_back(a);
  }

  int size() {
    return list.size();
  }
};
```

Also, such method allows you to define whether or not a particular descendant class should be treated as being distinct with its parent.